# How do I write a conditional to test which page I'm on in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I would like to do is to not show the headder in my rails app if the user is on the home page. Right now, the header is rendered in this line in application.html.erb:

```
<%= render('layouts/header') %>
```

What I'd like to do is put a conditional so that this doesn't get rendered if I'm on the home page. I think it should be something like:

```
<%= render('layouts/header') if not @homepage %>
```

where I set @homepage to true in the controller for the homepage. Does this approach make sense within the rails framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, the easiest is probably:

```
<%= render('layouts/header') unless params[:controller] == 'homepage' %>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works with one small adjustment: the controller is 'application' and the action is 'home' so the markup becomes: `<%= render('layouts/header') unless params[:action] == 'home' %>`

Comment: There are a few other ways to achieve this btw, you should read up on `content_for` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-content_for.

Comment: @jonnil - thanks for the link to railsguides.org. That looks like a fantastic resource.